# Xamarin Forms: Open menu by custom button in MasterDetail based project

Tags: xamarin, master-detail

In my  MasterDetail based  project, I need a custom appearence for the navigation part for a specific detail page. To avoid rendering a custom Navigation, I set

```
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

so navigation disappear an then I create by grid a  background and a button like:

```
<Grid>
   <Image Source="BackgroundImage.png"/> <!-- This should fill the grid -->
   <Image Source="back_button" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFit" >
      <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Handle_Tapped"/>
      </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Handle_Tapped should be manage the open/hide menu of master detail. I think i need to manage the IsPresented properties like

```
    MasterDetailPage nav = new MasterDetailPage();
    nav.IsPresented = true;
```

but that do nothing. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to change the presentation via the `IsPresented` property. The problem with your attempt is, that you create a new `MasterDetailpage` instead of using the active one.

Check if the current mainpage is a `MasterDetailPage` and change the presentation there:

```
if (Application.Current.MainPage is MasterDetailPage mdp)
{
    mdp.IsPresented = true;
}
```

**Edit / important hint**

The above solution works only, if the current Mainpage is a `MasterDetailPage`. Otherwise you are not able to show the menu from the page.

For a custom logic / custom slide-in/out menu, checkout the [Nuget-Package "SlideOverKit"](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit).

Comment: the page where I use button is a Detail page. From there I wanto present menu.

Comment: But your `DetailPage` is part of a `MasterDetailPage`. Right? If so, try the code in my answer. The code checks the current MainPage for `MasterDetailpage`.

Comment: Tx. Putting your code on my Handle_Tapped, if clause is false. So my main page is not Masterdetail.

Comment: So I misunderstood you. Can you change the Navigation to use a MasterDetailPage as a parent? Instead of directly navigating to your DetailPage? That would be the right way. Otherwise you have to implement a custom logic to show a custom menu (I edited my answer)

Comment: @doxsi Can you mark these answer as accepted (if it helped you). then it is easy for others to find a solution as well. Tanks